# Proving a total-order is a well-order if and only if every initial segment is determined by an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I managed to prove the $\longrightarrow$ part, but I'm not entirely sure how to prove the second part. I can assume by contradiction that the total order $(X, \leq)$ is not a well-order, which means there is an infinite monotonically-decreasing sequence, but how do I arrive to a contradiction? Can I show there exists an initial segment which is not determined by any element in $X$?

Would appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: Presumably you're only looking at *proper* initial segments. (Also, can you verify what "determined by an element" means? I'm pretty sure I know what it means, but I don't think it's common usage.)

Comment: If what you presumed in your answer is a proper initial segment then yes ("is the set of elements << some fixed element." ). My bad, I haven't really encountered the term proper initial segment until now.

Comment: "Proper" just means it's not the whole thing - $X$ is an initial segment of itself, but not a proper initial segment of itself.

Comment: @Dylan132 Without "proper", the statement would be false for limit ordinals.

Comment: @BrianO Actually if by "determined by" we mean "set of elements $<$ some fixed element," the statement would be wrong for *every* ordinal.

Comment: @NoahSchweber touché

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm confused, what do you mean by what you said? If we exclude the empty set and X itself, such that each initial segment is proper ("is the set of elements << some fixed element."), does the claim still hold?

Comment: @Dylan132 The emptyset isn't the problem - the problem is if you consider all of $X$ as an initial segment of itself. Then this is **never** determined by a single element.

Answer (score 6):

By "determined by  an element" I presume you mean "is the set of elements $<$ some fixed element." If this is the case, then: suppose $a_1>a_2> . . .$ is a descending sequence. Is there an initial segment of $X$ corresponding, in some way, to this sequence? Why is this initial segment not determined by an element?

---

EDIT: As a further hint (and based on the comments below), think about, say, $X=$negative integers. Then:

- Is $X$ well-ordered?
- What is an initial segment of $X$ not "determined by" any element?
- How does that initial segment relate to the descending sequence $-1>-2>-3>...$?

Then, same question with $Y=$negative integers and $-\infty$:

- What is an initial segment of $Y$ not "determined by" any element?
- How does that initial segment relate to the descending sequence $-1>-2>-3> . . .$?

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I'm gonna blame my cat for slowing down my typing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My thesis will be dedicated to "[people]; and to my cat, whose nonexistence greatly simplified the writing process."

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, why would there be an initial segment corresponding to the sequence? I might be wrong, but what if there exist infinitely many elements between a1 and a2? And if it does correspond to an initial segment, how do I prove that the set {x | x>a1} has no least element?

Comment: @Dylan132 It's not quite that simple. Certainly the sequence of $a_i$s isn't an initial segment, itself - I'm talking about an initial segment which is associated to it in a certain way. HINT: For each $i$, $\{x: x<a_i\}$ is an initial segment . . .

Comment: Isn't every (proper) initial segment of the negative integers determined by an element in that sense?

Comment: @GME No - the empty set is an initial segment not determined by an element. (Although for a second I got confused, and edited my answer to assume a least element. :P Darn empty set!)

Comment: Hmm, $1 + \omega^*$ (bottom element + negative integers).

Comment: @BrianO $\{\omega*\}$ would then be an initial segment not determined by an element.

Comment: @GME Ah, doh. So, sure -- same approach works then: given an infinite descending sequence $a_0 > a_1 > ...$, the initial segment "corresponding to it" does the trick.

Comment: @GME Ya we're on the same page (literally, too).

Comment: @BrianO Right! Don't know why I've found this so tricky.

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward proof, that is without contradiction, using the same arguments and ideas. This has the advantage that you do not need to use the axiom of choice (or the weaker axiom of dependent choice) to find this strictly decreasing sequence that is used there.

To be more specific, take a non-empty subset $A\subseteq X$ and consider the set

$$I:=\bigcap_{x\in A}I(x),$$

where $I(x):=\{y\in X:y<x\}$ is the initial segment determined by an element
$x\in X$. This is clearly a (proper) initial segment of $X$ and so it is determined by an element, say $z\in X$. Thus, we have that $I=I(z)$. This element $z\in X$ now is the least element of $A$. Indeed, if this is not the case then, there exists $x\in A$ such that $x<z$ and so $x\in I(z)=I$ and by the definition of $I$ it follows that $x\in I(x)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes - I wrote my answer explicitly continuing the OP's line of attack, but this is the "right" proof.